# Word VBA: Table cell range to text file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to copy a table like [this](http://www.allmusic.com/album/heroes-mw0002315317) in a word document and extract only the track titles and composers. The selecting of the range goes according to plan:

```
Dim myCells As Range
With ActiveDocument
    Set myCells = .Range(Start:=.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Start, _
        End:=.Tables(1).Cell(.Tables(1).Rows.Count, 3).Range.End)
    myCells.Select
End With
```

Now, when I copy this selection manually and paste it into notepad, I get exactly what I want:

```
Title
Composer
Title
Composer
etc.
```

However, I want to write this selection automatically into a text file. When I try to do this, all content is stuffed in one line of text and little squares (paragraph signs?) pop up everywhere.

How would be I be able to get the result of the manual copying, using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Allmusic()
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String, tempStr As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyAr() As String
    
    '~~> Name of Output File
    FlName = "C:\Sample.Txt"

    '~~> Get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 2 To .Tables(1).Rows.Count
            
            '~~> THIS LINE WILL NOT REFLECT CORRECTLY IN THE BROWSER
            '~~> PLEASE REFER TO THE SCREENSHOT OR THE ATTACHED FILE
            tempStr = Replace(.Tables(1).Cell(i, 3).Range.Text, "", "")
            
            If InStr(1, tempStr, Chr(13)) Then
                MyAr = Split(tempStr, Chr(13))
                Print #filesize, MyAr(0)
                Print #filesize, MyAr(1)
            Else
                Print #filesize, tempStr
            End If
            Print #filesize, ""
        Next i
    End With

    Close #filesize
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**SAMPLE FILE**

http://sdrv.ms/Mo7Xel

Download the file and run the procedure `Sub Allmusic()`

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It almost works. Here are the results: http://db.tt/RWPwco2i. As you can see, the two lines in each cell are combined so maybe I need an additional 'for each line loop' or something. You can also see the paragraph symbol at the end of each line, which has probably to do with the encoding.

Comment: May I see your word doc file?

Comment: BTW it is not combined. It is one below the other. Do you want a space between each line or after every Composer? Regarding the para mark, that can be easily removed.

Comment: I just noticed that when copy the text file's content into word it does skip lines between title and composer.. So how do I get it to skip lines in the text file? Here's the .docm file I'm working on: http://db.tt/0VWVOIL6. If you repaste the content there, you should get the same result.